# NestJS 9.4.0 crashes while initializing the Fastify CSRF module

Tags: nestjs, csrf, fastify

I installed the @fastify/csrf-protection package for NestJS 9.4.0 to protect it, but it gives me an error with end. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong and what it should look like? I've been struggling to solve this for a long time, ChatGPT suggests everything is fine. The various examples I found had a similar implementation to me. And I have added decorators for Nest so they don't conflict with Passport. I don't have checks or calls to the CSRF method in controllers because it should work globally for all routes.

**Main Code:**

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import {
  FastifyAdapter,
  NestFastifyApplication,
} from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import { fastifyCookie } from '@fastify/cookie';
import { ThrottlerModule } from '@nestjs/throttler';
import fastifyCsrf from '@fastify/csrf-protection';
import { FastifyInstance } from 'fastify';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter(),
  );
  const fastifyInstance: FastifyInstance = app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance();
  fastifyInstance
    .addHook('onRequest', async (req, res) => {
      req.socket['encrypted'] = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
    })
    .decorateReply('setHeader', function (name: string, value: unknown) {
      this.header(name, value);
    })
    .decorateReply('end', function () {
      this.send('');
    });
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
  const port = configService.get<string>('PORT', '');

  // Throttler - Protection
  app.enableCors({
    origin: '*',
    methods: 'GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE',
    allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, Authorization',
    credentials: true,
  });

  // XCSRF - Protection
  app.use(fastifyCookie);
  app.use(fastifyCsrf, {
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: 'strict',
      path: '^/',
      secure: true,
    },
  });

  await app.listen(port);
}
bootstrap();
```

**Error:**

```
[Nest] 1132  - 02.05.2023, 14:15:59   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Unexpected CHAR at 1, expected END
TypeError: Unexpected CHAR at 1, expected END
    at mustConsume (H:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-app\server\node_modules\@fastify\middie\node_modules\path-to-regexp\src\index.ts:157:11)
    at parse (H:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-app\server\node_modules\@fastify\middie\node_modules\path-to-regexp\src\index.ts:227:5)
    at stringToRegexp (H:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-app\server\node_modules\@fastify\middie\node_modules\path-to-regexp\src\index.ts:493:25)
    at pathToRegexp (H:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-app\server\node_modules\@fastify\middie\node_modules\path-to-regexp\src\index.ts:620:10)
    at Object.use (H:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-app\server\node_modules\@fastify\middie\engine.js:23:16)
    at Object.use (H:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-app\server\node_modules\@fastify\middie\index.js:26:21)
    at FastifyAdapter.use (H:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-app\server\node_modules\@nestjs\core\adapters\http-adapter.js:14:30)
    at NestApplication.use (H:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-app\server\node_modules\@nestjs\core\nest-application.js:146:26)
    at H:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-app\server\node_modules\@nestjs\core\nest-factory.js:145:40
    at Function.run (H:\xampp\htdocs\facebook-app\server\node_modules\@nestjs\core\errors\exceptions-zone.js:10:13)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `await app.register(fastifyPlugin, options)` when working with plugins for fastify. `app.use` is for middleware which work differently

#### Code for `app.register` with `as any`

```js
await app.register(fastifyCsrf, {
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'strict',
    path: '^/',
    secure: true,
  },
} as any);
```

*Technically* you should be able to add `sessionPlugin: '@fastify/cookie'` to get Typescript to *not* complain, but [there's a bug with that at the moment](https://github.com/fastify/csrf-protection/issues/133)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253460/discussion-on-answer-by-jay-mcdoniel-nestjs-9-4-0-crashes-while-initializing-the); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.